# Micronaut Data - Error - relation does not exist for postgresDB

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to fetch the data from PostgresDB. Below is the configuration

Model Class

```
@MappedEntity(value = "user_tracking")
public class UserTracking {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String brandId;
    private String status; 
    private String brandName; 
}
```

Repository

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
public interface UserTrackingRepository extends PageableRepository<UserTracking, String>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT ut FROM UserTracking ut",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(ut) FROM UserTracking ut")
    Page<UserTracking> findAllDBActivities(Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

DB Service

```
public @NonNull Page<UserTracking> getDBActivityByPagination(int page, int size) throws Exception{
        Pageable pageable = Pageable.from(page,size,Sort.of(Sort.Order.desc("createdOn")));
        //return utRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return utRepository.findAllDBActivities(pageable);
    }
```

If I run the method `utRepository.findAllDBActivities(pageable)` getting below exception

```
Execption : io.micronaut.data.exceptions.DataAccessException: SQL Error executing Query: ERROR: relation "usertracking" does not exist
```

But If I run the method `utRepository.findAll(pageable)` I am able to receive the data.

EDIT:
As per denis, If I used sql query, i am getting different error.
Repository Code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user_tracking",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM user_tracking"
            )
    Page<UserTracking> findAllDBActivities(Pageable pageable);
```

Error:

```
13:27:55.973 [main] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing Query: select * FROM user_tracking ORDER BY user_tracking_.created_on DESC LIMIT 10 
io.micronaut.data.exceptions.DataAccessException: SQL Error executing Query: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_tracking_"
  Position: 38
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.operations.DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations.findStream(DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations.java:567)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.operations.DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations.lambda$findAll$6(DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations.java:593)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.operations.DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations.lambda$executeRead$18(DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations.java:768)
    at io.micronaut.data.connection.support.AbstractConnectionOperations.executeWithNewConnection(AbstractConnectionOperations.java:143)
```

What is the issue with configuration?
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You defined the table name as `user_tracking`. But your SQL query has `UserTracking`, make sure you understand that Micronaut Data JDBC queries are written using SQL, not JPQL.

Comment: Please see updated question. I am geeting error : ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_tracking_"

Comment: If I do not used pageable then code is working